# Query to find record with the most matching columns, where non-matching columns have a space?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**The Problem**

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in SQL Server to find the best matching record.  Given 5 input parameters @A, @B, @C, @D, and @E (all varchar50) that correspond to the 5 columns A, B, C, D, and E in my table, I'd like to find the record with the most matching columns.  Each column that doesn't match in the chosen record should contain a space ' '.

For example, if I have the input "Sony", "PlayStation", "Controller", "Black", "Damaged", and my table contains the following columns:

```
"Sony"  "Playstation"  "Unit"   "Black"  "Damaged"
"Sony"  "Playstation"  " "      " "      " "
```

It should return the second row, because 2 parameters match and for the 3 that don't, there are spaces.  I don't want to return the first row because even though 4 parameters match, the middle one does not match and it is not a space.  If it had been a space, the first row would have been the winner.

**My Approach**

There are various specifics that I cannot reveal, but my basic approach (note that I'm an SQL novice) was to test every combination from MOST specific to LEAST specific.  So my query would look something like this:

```
-- start with most specific
SELECT * FROM dbo.Items WHERE
   A = @A
   B = @B
   C = @C
   D = @D
   E = @E

-- if no matches, try next
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
SELECT * FROM dbo.Items WHERE
   A = @A
   B = @B
   C = SPACE(1)
   D = @D
   E = @E

... etc.
```

In my case, I only need to really test 16 configurations, because some of the permutations will never exist.  Even so, this seems like a very inefficient way to achieve what I want.  On top of that, it's not even working.  It seems like comparing against spaces is problematic because of some auto-trimming that's going on.  In any case, my current approach seems inefficient and it doesn't work - so I turn to you for help.

Comment: So basically sort on the fewest number of incorrect matches?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, I want to return either ONE record, or none at all.  If a record is returned, it should match everything perfectly except for the " ".

Comment: btw, Dalal, I think you may have more than one match if, for example, there's a match in colB and a space in colC in one row, and a space in colB and a match in colC in another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
-- Temp table to play with
SELECT 1 AS Id, 'Sony' AS A, 'Playstation' AS B, 'Unit' AS C, 'Black' AS D, 
    'Damaged' AS E
INTO #Items
UNION SELECT 2, 'Sony', 'Playstation', ' ', ' ', ' '

-- The query
DECLARE @a nvarchar(50), @b nvarchar(50), @c nvarchar(50), @d nvarchar(50), @e 

nvarchar(50)
SET @a = 'Sony'
SET @b = 'Playstation'
SET @c = 'Controller'
SET @d = 'Black'
SET @e = 'Damaged'

SELECT TOP 1 I.*
FROM (
    SELECT ID,
        CASE WHEN @a = a THEN 1 WHEN a = ' ' THEN 0 ELSE NULL END AS AResult,
        CASE WHEN @b = b THEN 1 WHEN b = ' ' THEN 0 ELSE NULL END AS BResult,
        CASE WHEN @c = c THEN 1 WHEN c = ' ' THEN 0 ELSE NULL END AS CResult,
        CASE WHEN @d = d THEN 1 WHEN d = ' ' THEN 0 ELSE NULL END AS DResult,
        CASE WHEN @e = e THEN 1 WHEN e = ' ' THEN 0 ELSE NULL END AS EResult
    FROM #Items
) IW
INNER JOIN #Items I ON I.ID = IW.ID
WHERE AResult IS NOT NULL AND BResult IS NOT NULL AND CResult IS NOT NULL 
    AND DResult IS NOT NULL AND EResult IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY AResult + BResult + CResult + DResult + EResult DESC
```

That should return this value:

```
"Sony"  "Playstation"  " "      " "      " "
```

If you change the temp table I played with to this:

```
SELECT 1 AS Id, 'Sony' AS A, 'Playstation' AS B, ' ' AS C, 'Black' AS D, 
    'Damaged' AS E
INTO #Items
UNION SELECT 2, 'Sony', 'Playstation', ' ', ' ', ' '
```

Then you should get

```
"Sony"  "Playstation"  " "   "Black"  "Damaged"
```

And finally, if you have this for your temp table example:

```
SELECT 1 AS Id, 'Sony' AS A, 'Playstation' AS B, 'Unit' AS C, 'Black' AS D, 
    'Damaged' AS E
INTO #Items
UNION SELECT 2, 'Sony', 'Playstation', 'Unit', ' ', ' '
```

Nothing will get returned, since both have 'Unit' in the third column.

Comment: How is he getting `'Unit'` back, when that data doesn't exist (in your second data example)?

Comment: why do you need the 'else null' portion of each case statement?

Comment: @Beth - to filter out NULL values?

Comment: I'm thinking you're wanting to set each score col value explicitly each time, so you don't have to set all the initial non-null values to null before scoring again.  I would think, though, that most cell values will remain null, only a few will change to determine a score, so clearing non-null values would be quicker than explicitly setting cells to null each time.  Depends on if he has concurrent users, how many rows he's searching, and how well searches match, though.

Comment: @Beth - He's not updating the base table at all - this is all taking place in the `SELECT` statement.  Concurrent users generate no problems with this.

Comment: @X-Zero -- correct; there's no mention anywhere in the user's question of updating anything.  I'm not sure where Beth got that from.

Comment: If you want to do it blind, that's fine, I usually like to test things out before implementing them.  To do that, I'll store interim results and then rewrite it without the updates after I know what it's doing.  He was asking for another approach, which is easier to understand in pieces.  I still don't see why you need to explicitly set the value to null, or to test for non-null across the 5 columns in the where clause.  Just add them, and if any are null, the sum will be null.  That should be all you have to test for.

Comment: It worked perfectly!  Thanks LittleBobbyTables and thank you to everyone else who contributed.

Answer (score 1):

I would score each of the 5 comparisons (between columns A-E) and then add up the scores.

When colA = colA on any row, it scores a 1.

When colA <> colA and the second row's colA = ' ', score a 0.

leave the remaining rows unscored (null values for colA's score)

the best match(es) will have the highest score with no null scores in any column.

make sense?

here's a sample update statement to set the column's scores:

```
update table
set scoreAcol = scoreA, scoreAcol = scoreB, scoreCcol = scoreC, scoreDcol = scoreD, scoreEcol = scoreE
from
    (select
    case when cola = @a then 1 when cola= ' ' then 0 end as scoreA,
    case when colb = @b then 1 when colb= ' ' then 0 end as scoreb,
    case when colc = @c then 1 when colc= ' ' then 0 end as scorec,
    case when cold = @d then 1 when cold= ' ' then 0 end as scored,
    case when cole = @e then 1 when cole= ' ' then 0 end as scoree) s
from table
```

I am assuming you'll set all non-null scores to null before scoring again.

To total a row's scores, just

```
update table set score = scoreAcol + scoreBcol + scoreCcol + scoreDcol + scoreEcol
```

and any null values will cause the `score` value to be null.  Then to find your top scoring matches, you can sort by `score` descending.

Comment: Somewhat, but SQL just doesn't work that way.  While I agree with scoring the columns, SQL is inherently _set_ based, and handling rows in the manner you suggest isn't optimal - you seem to be thinking like an imperative programmer.  This doesn't even necessarily match the OP's data, as rows in SQL are inherently **unordered**, and at minimum you'd have to score _all_ rows anyways (even to get a 0 score).

Comment: I'm not saying use a cursor to iterate through each row, I'm saying introduce 5 new 'score' columns and use 5 update statements to set the scores.

Comment: ... Except that presumes that the OP will only be searching for 1 thing, and I highly doubt that to be the case.  And if you're suggesting to run an update so he can search for multiple things, that immediately eliminates the possibility of other users from searching the database concurrently.  You _might_ be able to do something with temp tables, but performance of a good `SELECT` should be enough to do this on the fly.

Comment: @X-Zero, actually it turns out that I AM only searching for one thing. I apologize for not making it clear in my post.  I want to find the BEST single row, or not return anything at all.  I'm not sure if Beth's approach will work or not, but some sample SQL would be nice.  EDIT: Never mind, I see what you're saying.  No, I'll be searching for multiple things.

Comment: the controller/unit comparison would fail, colC would contain a null value, so the total score across the 5 columns would be null, invalidating the row as a solution

Comment: #read earlier condition as 'else 0' only#  It's always best to explicitly declare _all_ conditions.  Especially if the scoring columns were defined as `NOT NULL`, I'm unsure of what would happen (ie, default to 0, throw an error?).

Comment: no, the default score is null, not 0, no error.  the row value stays null just like it always was.  Now, to run the scoring method again, you'd need to null out the existing non-null values...

Answer (score 0):

In SQl Server you could use CTEs and Nullif something like this (untested)

```
declare @a int = 1
, @B int = 2
, @c int= 3
, @d int= 4
, @E int- 5
```

;with counts (id, ACount, BCount,CCount,DCount,ECount)
AS
(select id, sum(case when A= @a or nullif(a, '')is null then 1 else 0 end) as ACount
, sum(case when b= @b or nullif(b, '')is null then 1 else 0 end) as bCount
, sum(case when c= @c or nullif(c, '')is null then 1 else 0 end) as cCount
, sum(case when d= @d or nullif(d, '')is null then 1 else 0 end) as dCount
, sum(case when e= @e or nullif(e, '')is null then 1 else 0 end) as eCount
from dbo.items)

, totals (id,Totalcount)
AS
(select id, max(ACount+BCount+CCount+DCount+ECount) as totalCount  from counts 
where Acount<>0 and BCount<>0 and CCount<>0 and DCount<> 0 And ECount<>0 
group by id)

select i.id, i.a, i.b, i.c, i.d, i.e
from dbo.items i
join totals t on i.id = t.id 
Of course the parameters woud be whatever their real definitions were.